# 3D Rotation: Rotating around a rotated axis

Tags: javascript, svg, 3d, rotation

[Old Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8A96s/embedded/result/)

By the way, the keyboard controls for my fiddles are as follows:

**Use the arrow keys to navigate.**

**Up and down adjust rotation around the x-axis.**

**Left and right adjust rotation around the y-axis.**

**Press 'z' or 'x' to rotate around the z-axis**

***UPDATE***

Well, it looks like I am getting closer to my goal, yet there are still some issues.

I've attempted to use a different rotation method, and everything works, until you try rotating around the x-axis(up or down arrows). Tests can be done for this in [***this newly updated fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/V6KZD/1/).

Other than that, some of the rotations can be seen as working.

**For example:**

**-Rotate 90° around the x-axis (up or down arrows - you'll be seeing the top or bottom)**

**-Rotate a little ways around the y-axis and then back to the origin (left or right arrows)**

*----*You should see that the rotation behaves as the z-axis rotation would if the object was at the absolute origin (success)*

**-Rotate a little ways around the z-axis and then back to the origin (`z` or `x` on the keyboard)**

*----*You should see that the rotation behaves as the y-axis rotation would if the object was at the absolute origin (success)*

End example...

Next Example...

**A test can be done to prove the failure as well:**

**-Rotate 90° around the y-axis (left or dright arrows - you'll be seeing the left or right side)**

**-Rotate a little ways around the z-axis and then back to the origin (`z` or `x` on the keyboard)**

*----*You should see that the rotation behaves as the x-axis rotation would if the object was at the absolute origin (success)*

**-Rotate a little ways around the x-axis and then back to the origin (up or down arrows)**

*----*The rotation should behave as the z-axis would behave if the object was at its absolute origin, yet it does not. Instead, it behaves as the x-axis rotation does at the origin (fail!)*

Once again, I am still very confused as to why this is failing, and if anyone could help, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!.

***More info..***

The area's responsible for the rotation in the code are shown below. I understand that it may be difficult to understand, yet just by looking at the `rotate2` function, it should be quite self explanitory what exactly I am doing. I am iterating through the start and end points of gridlines, and sending the (x,y,z) coordinates to the rotate function, then applying the return to the gridlines.

```
function rotate2(Xr, Yr, Zr, x, y, z)
{
    //Cosine
    this.C = function(v)
    {
        return Math.cos(v);
    }.bind(this);

    //negative cosine
    this.nC = function(v)
    {
        return (Math.cos(v)) * -1;
    }.bind(this);

    //Sine
    this.S = function(v)
    {
        return Math.sin(v);
    }.bind(this);

    //negative sine
    this.nS = function(v)
    {
        return (Math.sin(v)) * -1;
    }.bind(this);

    //First Matrix row
    //{
       var aa = (this.C(Yr)) * (this.C(Zr));
       var ab = (this.nC(Yr)) * (this.S(Zr));
       var ac = this.S(Yr);
    //}

    //Second Matrix Row
    //{
       var ba = (this.S(Xr) * this.S(Yr) * this.C(Zr)) + (this.C(Xr) * this.S(Zr));
       var bb = (this.nS(Xr) * this.S(Yr) * this.S(Zr)) + (this.C(Xr) * this.C(Zr));
       var bc = this.nS(Xr) * this.C(Yr);
    //}

    //Third Matrix Row
    //{
       var ca = (this.nC(Xr) * this.S(Yr) * this.C(Zr)) + (this.S(Xr) * this.S(Zr));
       var cb = (this.C(Xr) * this.S(Yr) * this.S(Zr)) + (this.S(Xr) * this.C(Zr));
       var cc = this.C(Xr) * this.C(Yr);
    //}

    //__          __   ___   ____
    //|aa   ab   ac|   |x|   |nX|
    //|ba   bb   bc| * |y| = |nY|
    //|ca   cb   cc|   |z|   |nZ|


    var nX = (x * aa) + (y * ab) + (z * ac);
    var nY = (x * ba) + (y * bb) + (z * bc);
    var nZ = (x * ca) + (y * cb) + (z * cc);

    var rtrnObj = new Object();

    rtrnObj.x = nX;
    rtrnObj.y = nY;
    rtrnObj.z = nZ;

    return rtrnObj;
}

function drawGrid()
{
    var placeObject;

    var axis;
    var plane;
    var line;
    var point;
    var multiplex;

    for(axis in Grid)
    {
        for(plane in Grid[axis])
        {
            for(line in Grid[axis][plane])
            {
                for(point in Grid[axis][plane][line])
                {
                    placeObject = rotate2(object_info.grid.x_rotation, object_info.grid.y_rotation, object_info.grid.z_rotation, Grid[axis][plane][line][point].x, Grid[axis][plane][line][point].y, Grid[axis][plane][line][point].z);

                    //Here, I am centering the coordinates on the screen.
                    //If you were to watch in the debugger, the values for the
                    //coordinates will range from (+) my maximum dimesion
                    //(in this example, my maximum dimension is 3 inches) to
                    //(-) my maximum dimension. I add this to the center point
                    // of the screen in order to center the coordinates

                    placeObject.z += (object_info.grid.center.z - player.z);
                    //This is used for distancing, even though I am not 
                    //encorporating vanishing points in this example.

                    placeObject.x += object_info.grid.center.x;

                    placeObject.y += object_info.grid.center.y;


                    //Convert To Pixels
                    //{
                        placeObject.x *= 12 * ppi;
                        placeObject.y *= 12 * ppi;
                    //}

                    //Convert To screen coordinates
                    //{
                        placeObject.x += (View.w / 2);
                        placeObject.y = (placeObject.y * -1) + (View.h / 2);
                    //}

                    if(point === 'a')
                    {
                        Lines[(axis + plane + line)].setAttributeNS(null, "x1", placeObject.x.toString());
                        Lines[(axis + plane + line)].setAttributeNS(null, "y1", placeObject.y.toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Lines[(axis + plane + line)].setAttributeNS(null, "x2", placeObject.x.toString());
                        Lines[(axis + plane + line)].setAttributeNS(null, "y2", placeObject.y.toString());
                        Lines[(axis + plane + line)].style.stroke = '#000000';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The matrix that illustrates my rotate function [can be found here](http://math.kennesaw.edu/~plaval/math4490/rotgen.pdf), *page 118*, *figure 9.1*

[image: 3D Rotation Matrix]

Comment: I think you need to isolate your code, you can't really expect people to trawl through lots of code. It sounds like you are describing 'gimbal lock' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal_lock and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno If so, there's a couple of different ways to get around it. None are for the faint hearted without some library, and you may want to look into quaternions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and sorry for the large blocks of code. I'll try to cut out the area where the issue is at and post that. This was an example from a much bigger project, and I had to slice and dice it so that I could make a JSFiddle for it. I'm trying to make a 3D path editor that would allow a user to generate a 3D widget. The program then generates a .js file that acts as a plugin to a screen builder which is used to construct HMI's for users within a mill scenario. Unfortunately, the 3D portion was canned because of this issue.

Comment: After investigating the links that you provided me, I truly think that this may be where my answer lies. Thanks you. I will need to really study up on this to fully understand it, but I may be able to figure it out from here. Once again, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if gimbal lock was my issue the first time around, yet quaternions proved to be very useful. With my [**newest update of the fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/V6KZD/1/) and of this question, I've come closer to solving this problem than ever before. I still am not sure why I do not have full functionality, as I expect there to be a simple bug in my code.

Comment: I keep thinking that the bug lies in my computation of the transformation matrix within the function `rotate2`, yet I've looked over it a number of times and I can't find anything wrong.